# Update table using JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to update a table using a JSON field in SQL.

```
{
    "RelationshipType" : [ 
        {
            "ID" : 1,
            "FromID" : 70,
            "ToID" : 12
        },
        {
            "ID" : 3,
            "FromID" : 80,
            "ToID" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Table structure

```
ID    |    FromID    |    ToID    |
1     |     10       |     12     |
2     |     42       |     17     |
3     |    100       |     1      |
```

If I update the table using the above mentioned JSON file in SQL server the output should be changed as below by matching the `FromID` to `ID`.

```
ID    |    FromID    |    ToID    |
1     |     70       |     12     |
2     |     42       |     17     |
3     |     80       |     1      |
```

In order to achieve this currently I am using the below query.

```
DECLARE @Relationship AS TABLE(FromID INT,ToID INT,ID INT)
INSERT INTO @Relationship (FromID,ToID,ID)
SELECT FromID, ToID, ID
FROM OPENJSON(@RelationshipType)
WITH (FromID INT, ToID INT, ID INT)
```

I am iterating the `@Relationship` table and updating the data. Is there a proper way to do it using JSON operations without iterating the temp table.

Comment: @PeterB, if I get this *"I am iterating the `@Relationship` table"* correctly, the point is not the reading of the JSON, but the udate *in one go*...

Comment: @Shnugo. Exactly, Is there a solution in order to update the table directly without feeding the data to a Temp Table or a CTE?

Comment: @HarshaW, just check my answer... You can use `UPDATE` with a JOIN, or - my prefered approach - an updatable CTE. At least for me this is better to read...

Comment: @Shnugo Sure, Ill try this and get back to you :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to specify the path `'$.RelationshipType'` in `OPENJSON()` to make it extract the data correctly.

Second, it is possible to JOIN `OPENJSON()` results just like any table, also using `UPDATE`, as follows:

```
UPDATE U
SET    FromID = J.FromID
FROM   YourTable AS U
JOIN   OPENJSON(@RelationshipType, '$.RelationshipType')
       WITH (ID INT, FromID INT, ToID INT) J
       ON J.ID = U.ID
```

See it in action:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c37ef5a175c0f19e0f990dc6a219ce26

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Your `OPENJSON` is missing the path... Isn't it?

```
DECLARE @relationshipType NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
    "RelationshipType" : [ 
        {
            "ID" : 1,
            "FromID" : 70,
            "ToID" : 12
        },
        {
            "ID" : 3,
            "FromID" : 80,
            "ToID" : 1
        }
    ]
}';
```

--This is to *mock-up* your existing data

```
DECLARE @ExistingTable AS TABLE(ID INT,FromID INT,ToID INT)
INSERT INTO @ExistingTable VALUES(1,10,12),(2,42,17),(3,100,1);
```

--The query will use two CTEs:
--1) Get the JSON data as list
--2) Bind the *new data* to the corresponding rows

```
WITH newData AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(@relationshipType,'$.RelationshipType')
    WITH (FromID INT, ToID INT, ID INT)
)
,updatableCTE AS
(
    SELECT et.*
          ,nd.FromID AS newFromID
          ,nd.ToID AS newToID
    FROM @ExistingTable et
    INNER JOIN newData nd ON et.ID=nd.ID
)
UPDATE updatableCTE SET FromID=newFromID
                       ,ToID=newToID;
```

--check the result

```
SELECT ID,FromID,ToID FROM @ExistingTable;
```

The result

```
ID  FromID    ToID
1     70        12
2     42        17
3     80         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enhancing @Peter B's answer

```
UPDATE X
SET    FromID = J.FromID
FROM   OPENJSON(@RelationshipType, '$.RelationshipType')
   WITH (ID INT, FromID INT, ToID INT) J
```